# Dojo 1.6.0 dijit byId returns null in Latest Chrome build

Tags: javascript, dojo

In the latest update of chrome, dijit's byId method is failing to return an object for an element which I know exists in the DOM.  Anyone else run into anything similar?

Comment: `dijit.byId` has nothing to do with an element in DOM (at least not directly) because that's where you should use `dojo.byId`. `dijit.byId` is used in widgets, can you pose some code?

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u92RY/) that demonstrates the difference between `dojo.byId` and `dijit.byId`. Running it with the latest Chrome works as expected.